# Define values of an array without using 'for' loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Is there any short way to define values of an array (without using 'for' loop)?

```
assigned = new boolean[rmsize](false);
```

Comment: Use the `{...}` notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for

```
boolean[] assigned = new boolean[]{false, true, false};//or any values you want
```

Notice that you don't set size of array since it will be determined by number of elements.

---

In case you want to create array with defined dimension and fill it with one element you can use `Arrays.fill(yourArray, element)`. This will fill `yourArray` with element you passed like

```
boolean[] assigned = new boolean[rmsize];//by default it is filled with false
Arrays.fill(assigned, true);
```

will set all elements in `assigned` to `true`.

Comment: What happens if the array size is unknown? This is the case.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos I am not sure is this what you ware looking for but could you check my edit?

Answer (score 2):

You used it in a wrong way, its not `()` its `{}`, also you cannot provide `dimension` when  you `initialize` your array.

e.g

```
assigned = new boolean[]{false, true};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set up an array where all elements are the same value:

```
boolean[] assigned = new boolean[rmsize];
Arrays.fill (assigned, true);
```

`Arrays` is in `java.util`.  There are `fill` methods for all primitive types, and a `fill` method that takes an `Object[]` array and works on any class type.